# Why does the output of this code look like this?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

In PHP language,

```
$var = ("!"^"@");
```

Why does the value of the line come out as "a?

Demo - https://3v4l.org/b0saN

Answer (score 1):

See [Bitwise Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.bitwise.php)

> If both operands for the &, | and **^ operators** are strings, then the operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that make up the strings and the result will be a string

```
"!" -> ASCII 33 -> 0b0100001
"@" -> ASCII 64 -> 0b1000000

    0100001
XOR 1000000
===========
    1100001 = ASCII 97 = "a"
```

Comment: thank you!!! My curiosity has been cleared.